# page indicator with tabhost

Tags: android, android-tabhost

Hi I want to create a page Indicator with tab host.
not just click on tab icon sliding the page tab also has to be changed 
how to do that?
thanks in advance

Comment: You can use fragments to do this. And tabhost has been depricated with above versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use tab, see this basic tutorial and start it.Hope, you will get an idea.
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-navigation-tabs-containing-listview-to-action-bar-in-android/

Use Jake Wharton's view pager indicator library.https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator for sliding.